# How to map diverse external datasources to a unified model in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, datamapper, data-mapping

I have a collection of documents with a given set of properties that my code expects. However, I need to populate this collection with data from various datasources that have completely different properties (or fields). This will require some form of field mapping.

There are many ways this could be accomplished:

1. Pull in data in my application layer, massage it into the correct format, then dump it into Mongo (this seems highly inefficient).
2. Dump data directly into a temporary collection in Mongo, then iterate through each document, perform the field mapping, and finally store it in the correct collection (this seems to be a better approach, but still awkward).
3. Same as option 2, but use a map (or similar) function to perform the field mapping (this seems to be a good choice, but the only things I find are related to map-reduce, which I doesn't appear to be the right method for this task).
4. Implement a data-mapper pattern, but I can't find any resources on that either (this would be my preferred solution, to separate application from persistence layer completely).

What would you suggest?

**Clarification:** I am using Laravel (PHP). Steps 1 would be all on the application layer, while steps 2 and 3 could be implemented with mongo scripts.

**Clarification Update:** The data is pulled in via Curl, then stored. The idea behind dumping it straight to the database would be to make the data pulls faster and not bog down the server (scenario 1). Options 2 and 3 would offload the mapping to the database-layer, which should be much more efficient, as there should be no network traffic per mapped document. I suppose it really boils down to if option 4 exists, and if not I can fall back on options 1 through 3, or a smart combination thereof (perhaps mapping on the database layer as the document is stored from the application layer).

Comment: This seems a bit broad for StackOverflow and the answer may depend on programming language and toolset. The first 3 options basically seem the same. For many programming languages, there are already mapping widgets that could make this relatively straightforward.

Comment: How is the external data being populated into MongoDb in the first place? Through a Web Service style API? I wouldn't recommend storing the data, only to copy the data again. It's a lot of busy work.